# Getting slack time in Job Shop with Transitions

Tags: python, or-tools

I am running a flexible job shop problem with alternatives and transition times.

Is it possible to determine the slack time on a machine; that is the time it is not either working or transitioning? The working time is obvious, but the transition time is dependent on the before and after jobs (selected from a matrix like routing travelling time), so not constant.

I can calculate this fairly easily after the fact in python outside of or-tools, i just wondered if it is possible for or-tools to return this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the circuit constraint to encode transitions, you can extend it:

```
model.Add(start[i] >= end[j] + transition[j, i]).OnlyEnforceIf(next[j][i])
```

into

```
model.Add(start[i] == end[j] + transition[j, i] + slack[i]).OnlyEnforceIf(next[j][i])
```

Thus `slack[i]` will be set as the waiting time before starting task i.
Then you need to decide what to do with the initial slack.

Comment: Thank you, i have implemented the slack as you suggested, and it seems to be working in the model. I haven't yet worked out how to get the slack out at the end, i assumed it would be solver.Value but no luck so far, will keep playing!

Comment: And now I've found my mistake, working now. Thanks again.